# StripeInvalidRequestError: Livemode requests must always be redirected via HTTPS

Tags: stripe-payments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ucr.png)

I am getting this kind of error while connecting to stripe .
can anyone please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your webpage via HTTPS so that you can make livemode requests from your webpage.

Comment: Means for that do i have to host that site first??

Comment: You can use test mode API key to make requests during development, and change to live mode key before deploying your application to production.